# Radak's commentary on Ezekiel

Tags: tanach

May I please have a translation of Radak's commentary on Ezekiel?

([44:17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.44.17?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en)):

והיה בבאם אל שערי החצר הפנימית. אם נאמר החצר הפנימית כמשמעו יהיה פירושו שער עזרת הכהנים והמזבח וממנו לשער האולם כי הכל הוא חצר ויהיה זה אם כן חדוש לעתיד כי בבגדי כהונה שהיו משמשים בהם צמר היה כמו שכתוב בתורת משה כי התכלת היא צמר צבוע בתכלת ואם נאמר כי דבר זה על עבודת כהן הגדול ביום הכיפורים לפני ולפנים שהיה עובד בבגדי פשתים איך קרא הדביר חצר והוא בית ואיך אמר בבאם ילבשו לשון רבים והעבודה ההיא לא היתה אלא בכהן גדול והיה הוא לבדו נכנס שם וביום הכפורים לבד:

Sefaria does not offer an English translation...

If I don't ask too much too...

([44:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.44.19?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Ezekiel.44.19.3&lang2=bi)):

ולא יקדשו את העם בבגדיהם. כי אם יגעו את העם בבגדי כהונה שהם קדש יראה שהם קדושים כמוהם ועל הדרך הזה ת"י ולא יתערבון עם עמא בלבושיהון:

I'm curious to know what it says about the sanctity of the clothes that it could put on the people...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly.

והיה בבאם אל שערי החצר הפנימית. אם נאמר החצר הפנימית כמשמעו יהיה פירושו שער עזרת הכהנים והמזבח וממנו לשער האולם כי הכל הוא חצר ויהיה זה אם כן חדוש לעתיד כי בבגדי כהונה שהיו משמשים בהם צמר היה כמו שכתוב בתורת משה כי התכלת היא צמר צבוע בתכלת ואם נאמר כי דבר זה על עבודת כהן הגדול ביום הכיפורים לפני ולפנים שהיה עובד בבגדי פשתים איך קרא הדביר חצר והוא בית ואיך אמר בבאם ילבשו לשון רבים והעבודה ההיא לא היתה אלא בכהן גדול והיה הוא לבדו נכנס שם וביום הכפורים לבד :

"And when they enter the gates of the inner court. If we say that "the inner court" is in its plain meaning, i.e., [that] it would refer to the gate of the priestly court and the altar and from there to the gate of the sanctuary for all [of these] are [part of] the court, then this would be innovation for the future, for the priestly garments that the priests would use were made of wool as it says in the Book of Moshe, for the techelet [blue] refers to wool dyed techelet [blue]. And if we say that this [the term "the inner court"] refers to the service of the High Priest on Yom Kippur before and behind [the entrance to the Holy of Holies] when he was serving [wearing] garments of flax, why did [the text] refer to the sanctuary as "court", for it is [actually] a house? And how did [the text] say "they shall wear" in plural, for, after all, that service is to be done only by the High Priest, and only he would enter there [the Holy of Holies] and only on Yom Kippur?"

ולא יקדשו את העם בבגדיהם. כי אם יגעו את העם בבגדי כהונה שהם קדש יראה שהם קדושים כמוהם ועל הדרך הזה ת"י ולא יתערבון עם עמא בלבושיהון:

"lest they make the people consecrated by [contact with] their vestments.  For if they touch the people with the priestly garments that are holy, they will see that they are holy like them, and in this manner Yonatan [=Targum Jonathan] translated "and they shall not mix with the people [wearing] their clothes."

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @Ootsutsuki You're welcome.

Comment: So does Radak argue that it is not a historical step but a prophetic one for the future? In fact, the text speaks of priests, in the plural, a task that was normally carried out by a single high priest in the holy of holys ... very strange this passage from Ezekiel ...